# What value do you use for initializing state variable of type number in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Let's say, I have a state variable called `amount` and I have an input field which changes the variable when we type in it. I don't want to show the initial value as `0`. With what should I initialize the state variable then? I tried initializing with `null` but console threw a warning:

```
Warning: 'value' prop on 'input' should not be null.
Consider using the empty string to clear the component or 'undefined' for uncontrolled components.
```

I've two questions now:-

1. Why input field throws a warning when it receives a value as `null`? I  tried googling but was not able to get a clear answer.
2. With what should I initialize number type state variables?

Comment: Hi @ShadowLeaf, Is this a typescript project..?

Comment: I am not sure you can use number type state for controlled input. ```event.target.value``` will return string (even for input type=number) and if you decide to parse it before setting a state, you won't be able to type decimals. Because if you type `3.` (three and a dot) it will be parsed to ```3``` (just three) since ```Number(3.)``` or Number ```(3.000)``` will be displayed as ```3```. This is why I believe a state for controlled number input should be of type string.

Comment: @JaiKumaresh It's JS project as of now.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan We can also use parseFloat for decimal numbers.

Comment: @ShadowLeaf You can parse string to number with a lot of ways. My point was that: what you type is not what will be in the state. If you type ```3.``` (three and dot) and then use ```setState(parseFloat("3."))``` you will get a state that is equal to ```3```, not to ```3.``` and that will remove the dot from the input, since it is controlled input . You won't be able to type a dot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me answer both your questions one by one:

##### 1. Why input field throws a warning when it receives value as `null`?

This warning is shown because React expects the `value` prop of a ***controlled*** input component to be a `string`, `number` (or `undefined` if input type is ***uncontrolled***<sup>***1***</sup>). When the value is set to `null`, React considers it as an incorrect value type, so it throws a warning to remind you to use an appropriate value type.

Key point to note from the official docs:<sup>***2***</sup>

> The value you pass to controlled components should not be undefined or null.

##### 2. With what should I initialize number type state variables?

If you don't want to show an initial value of `0`, you can initialize the state variable with an empty string (`''`). This way, the input field will appear empty initially, and `React` won't throw a warning that you're getting. This is also inferred from the official docs<sup>***2***</sup> which says:

> If you need the initial value to be empty (such as with the firstName field below), initialize your state variable to an empty string ('').

```js
const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // do whatever you want with amount by parsing it to number
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };
...
<input type="number" value={amount} onChange={handleChange} />
```

*[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6qlmtc?file=src%2FApp.tsx)*

---

##### References and further reading:

1. [Controlled and Uncontrolled components in React](https://www.scaler.com/topics/react/controlled-and-uncontrolled-components-in-react/)
2. [Controlling an input with a state variable](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#controlling-an-input-with-a-state-variable)
3. [Converting a string to number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/19090048)

Comment: This is the appropriate answer, with enough detail to cover what is the main problem and how to solve it. Good work.

Comment: Great response, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Typescript, you can do the following:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState<number | undefined>(undefined)
```

In other words, specify the type of your state to be either `number` or `undefined`.

Of course, when using `value`, you need to check whether or not it is `undefined`. If so, handle it; if not, use `value`

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use `''` or undefined to avoid the warnings for the empty inputs.

0 or NaN(null) values can also be used for initialising numeric state if appropriate.

Managing an extra `isInitialised` state var is second option to hide inputs until needed

Comment: You can't have undefined set on an input element (at all). because when you start writing in the input it converts the type `undefined` to `string`, then react shows the error `changing uncontrolled to controlled...etc`